# Floating and bouncing boxes across browser window – how to achieve

Tags: javascript, animation

[image]

I would like to have multiple boxes that are floating around and when they hit the border of the browser they bounce back… I tried to illustrate it on the image. 
The boxes should be clickable at the end.

Has anyone a recommendation for a JavaScript-framework? Or does someone know a tutorial for this kind of animation? 
It would be nice if I can get some inspiration for how to start this task, keeping it as easy as possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Look into HTML canvas: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API

Comment: You'd want to be using HTML5 (<canvas>) + Javascript. Google "html5 canvas bouncing balls box"... plenty of tutorials and samples. After you get the boundary and motion, then build a function to manage your objects... ie life/death/speed, etc.

Comment: you found the answer to your last question that you deleted? Was going to post an answer

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org) and the examples.
Something similar: http://paperjs.org/examples/bouncing-balls/

Click the "Source" at the top right corner to check the source code. If you change anything, and click "Run", your changes will take affect.

For example, if you change `this.gravity = 3;` to `this.gravity = 0;` on line 9, you basically finished creating something very similar.